# Adding cascade to doctrine annotations in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to add `cascade` to some columns in my existing database, but `doctrine:schema:update` doesn't recognize any changes within the annotations.

```
FROM:
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 */
private $user;

TO:
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $user;
```

Clearing the cache didn't help at all. Any other ideas?

Comment: cascade operations in Doctrine are done on PHP level – not on DB. See [last note in this section](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="your_definition")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
```